# Toolbar getting added automatically

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I am trying to bring the Navigation drawer on top of the ActionBar/Toolbar in the following code. The problem is, I *didn't add toolbar* in the xml file and the actionbar setting has been set to false in the *style.xml* file. However still an actionbar thingy is being added automatically in the window. I don't know what is causing this actionbar/toolbar to be added.

[image]

Following is the code:

**NavigationDrawer_Activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

  **<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>**    
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Layout Here"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_view_header_layout"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_view_list_items"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Questions:

- If I am not adding this toolbar, what is causing it to appear?
- How to bring the NavigationDrawer on top of this automagically added toolbar?

Best

Answer (score 0):

Remove the windowActionBar property and change your style parent to this:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

You are adding a toolbar here:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Remove this in order to not display a Toolbar?

Comment: I totally missed it. The problem is still here. The toolbar now covers the whole screen. And clicks on the navigation drawer list items doesn't work. Please see the edited NavigationDrawer_Activity.xml

Comment: Forgive me if I've misunderstood your question, but I've edited my answer. Seems you are adding a Toolbar, when you don't want one, just remove it?

Comment: No I wanted to remove the one that was automatically added by the theme. My requirement is to have slide navigation drawer on top of the manually added toolbar. However now when I add toolbar in the xml file, it fills the whole display and the items in the navgiation view have become unclickable

Comment: Do you need an AppBarLayout?

Comment: I think AppTheme.PopupOverlay maybe your culprit try removing it.

Comment: OK I solved the other problem. The only thing that is bugging me is, Click on navigation view items doesn't work. However long click work

Comment: You'll have to post your code or post another question regarding the click.

Answer (score 0):

In manifest

change

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

to

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```